# Efficiently make an int that has a 1 all 1s but one that is 0 stay 0

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have an assignment that asks to do a number of functions only using these operators:

! ~ & ^ | + << >>

In some of the problems it is useful to make some integer, x, become all 1s if it contains any 1s but stay 0 if it is 0. The reason I do this is so I can return y or z like this:

```
// One of the two conditional values is now 0
int conditionalA = mask&y;
int conditionalB = ~mask&z;

// One of the values is combined with 0 using |
int out = conditionalA|conditionalB;

return out;
```

where I made mask like this:

```
// Make any x other than 0 all 1s
int mask = x;
mask |= mask>>1;
mask |= mask>>2;
mask |= mask>>4;
mask |= mask>>8;
mask |= mask>>16;

mask |= mask<<1;
mask |= mask<<2;
mask |= mask<<4;
mask |= mask<<8;
mask |= mask<<16;
```

There must be a better way to make mask all 1s or 0s but I can't think of a more efficient solution. Again, it is important that 0 remains 0 if x was 0.

**Edit**: If statements are not an option

Comment: I guess you can't use literal constants?

Comment: I could, but with further restrictions (only allowed to write numbers between 0x0 - 0xff and shift if they need to be bigger). I don't see how they would help though

Comment: Take a peek at this collection of bit-twiddling hacks: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming 2's complement:

```
int mask = !x + ~0;
```

The `!` maps any nonzero value to `0` and `0` to `1`, then we add `~0` (`-1`) to get `-1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this answer.  What _integer_ is ~0?  (Does the standard even specify?)  Given that integer overflow is undefined, why do you think that 1 + ~0 == 0?

Comment: I guess this works if ~0 == -1, but I don't think that's guaranteed.

Comment: @Joshua Green that's guaranteed for 2's complement environments. Otherwise using `0u` for unsigned arithmetic will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `0u` isn't guaranteed to work, for then `~0u` is unlikely to fit in a (signed) `int` and trying to store it in `mask` will yield implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
x = (x | -x) >> 31; // Note this is implementation specific.
```

Ok, I'm using `-` which isn't allowed, so it's not the right answer here. I'll leave it here as a novelty.

Comment: Doesn't work, right? If x started as `4`, it ends as `0xfffffffc`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It would. That's why he used `-`, not `~`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Wouldn't that be `0 | -0` which is `0 | 0`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using -ve, not logical inverse. I could clarify the comment, it was only there for the character limit...

Comment: In that case, the problem is that `-` doesn't seem to be among the list of allowed operators.

Comment: `-` could be replaced with `~` and `+`.  But it still gives the wrong answer.

Comment: That uses - which is not allowed

Comment: I agree, but it is a rule for the assignment

Comment: How did this get 3 upvotes when it doesn't give right answers even not considering the disallowed `-`?  It gives incorrect results any time `x` starts as a power of two.

Comment: Looks good now - I wouldn't worry about the "implementation specific".  Every other answer here assumes two's complement already.  On another note, you could just replace `-x` with `(~x + 1)` and meet all the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working one I think (assumes two's complement arithmetic):

```
x = ~!!x + 1;
```

How did I get there?

First, `!!x` turns any non-zero vale into 1, and 0 stays 0.  Then, using 2's complement equivalency for negation `-x = ~x + 1`, presto!

Comment: Clever, but another part of the assignment is trying to make a habit of using minimal amounts of operators, so I'm going to stick with `mask = !x+~0;`. Thank you though

Comment: If you want fewer operators, why not `mask = !x + 0xffffffff`?  Edit: sorry - didn't see your extra restriction in the comment above.

Comment: Another arbitrary rule is not being able to write literals higher than 0xff, otherwise that would be even better

Answer (score 0):

Most answers seem to be implementation-specific, particularly assuming 2s complement.

They are great, but in case that's not acceptable, I have this version that doesn't rely on representation as much. In particular, it supports 1s complement and sign-magnitude representations:

```
x = ~0 << (!x << 2 << sizeof(x)) // minimal brackets
// x = (~0) << (((!x) << 2) << sizeof(x)) // same code with maximum brackets, removing the ambiguity from the order of operations
```

If you know your system's integer size, you can replace `sizeof(x)` with a fixed number.

**Explanation:**

1. We first start by acknowledging that in all mentioned representations, no matter the size, `0` will always be `...0000` (all bits are `0`), and `1` will always be `...0001` (all bits are `0`, except the last one).
2. From this, we know that `~0` will always be `...1111` (all bits are `1`).
3. Now, the key idea is that we will shift this value (`~0`, all ones) to the left by our number (after some transformations).
4. If our number is `0`, then no matter how many times we shift by `0`, the resulting number will always remain the same (that is `~0`).
5. If our number is larger than `0`, then after enough shifts all bits will be set to `0`.
6. This is the reason why we're shifting to the left. Overflow on right shift operator can sometimes use the sign bit to fill the vacant bit. However, the left shift operator is guaranteed to fill with `0`s on overflow. [Source: [C99 standard, section "6.5.7 Shift operators", subsections 3, 4 and 5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) ]

So, our first iteration of the program looks like this:

```
x = (~0) << x;
```

This obviously doesn't work, for a number of reasons:

1. If `x` is negative, then the left shift behavior is undefined.  [Source: [C99 standard, section "6.5.7 Shift operators", subsection 3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) ]
2. If `x` is smaller than the bit size of the integer, we will not shift to the left enough times, leaving us with something like `1100...0000`, or even with `1111...1110` in the worst case scenario.

So, let's say we replace `x` with `!x`, and repeat the shift for the bit size of our integer:

```
int new_x = ~0; // 1111...1111
new_x = new_x << (!x); // 1111...1110
new_x = new_x << (!x); // 1111...1100
new_x = new_x << (!x); // 1111...1000
//... and so on until we've done this 8*sizeof(x) times
```

1. If `x` was anything other than `0`, then `!x` will be `0`, and no amount of shifting will change the `~0`, leaving us with `~0` in the end.
2. However, if `x` was `0`, then `!x` will be `1`, and after `8*sizeof(x)` left shifts, we will get a `0`.

This is starting to look good, except that it's much longer than your initial version, and the code varies depending on the size of the `int`. So, we use one final trick to collapse the multiple lines into one - *we left shift `!x` by some amount*. Once again, we have 2 possible outcomes:

1. If `!x` is `0`, then no matter how many times we left shift that `0`, it will always be `0`.
2. However, if `!x` is `1`, then shifting it to the left `N` times is equivalent to multiplying it by `2^N`. This is possible because up to a certain value of `N`, all mentioned representations are identical. Although, we have to be careful not to overdo it. Thankfully, this is not an issue, because the size of an integer is typically much smaller than the value of `N` where this becomes a problem.

Let's see how it works if we know our system's `int` size:

```
x = (~0) << ((!x) << 5)
```

In the example above, our system's integer size is 4 bytes, or 32 bit.

If `!x` is `1`, then `(!x) << 5` will be `1 << 5`, or `32`. Then, we simply left shift our 4-byte `~0`, or `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`, by `32`.

In binary form, `32` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000`, irrespective of the mentioned representation. This is an example of what I meant earlier when I said that the size of an integer is much smaller than the size of `N` where it becomes a problem.

In fact, we can calculate the exact shift factor for any given integer size, and it's:

```
shift_factor = 8*sizeof(x)
```

`8` is just `1 << 3`. However, we are forbidden from using multiplication. So, we can approximate this with the following expression:

```
shift_factor = (1 << 2) << sizeof(x)
```

When `sizeof(x) == 1`, the smallest value it can take, `shift_factor == (1 << 2) << 1`. `shift_factor` binary form is `00001000`, which is `8` under all 3 representations. Thus, we shift 1 byte by 8 bit, obtaining `0`.

When `sizeof(x) == 2`, `shift_factor == 16`. `shift_factor` binary form is `00000000 00010000`, which is `16` under all 3 representations. This means we shift 2 bytes by 16 bits, obtaining `0`.

When `sizeof(x) == 3`, `shift_factor == 32`. This time, we shift 3 bytes (24 bits) by 32 bits, overshooting. But this is not a problem, as we still end up with `0`.

When `sizeof(x) == 4`, `shift_factor == 64`. I hope you can see the trend by now, `shift_factor` grows faster than the size of `x`. To be precise, `N` grows exponentially, while `sizeof(x)` grows linearly.

At the same time, bit size of `x` grows 8 times faster than `sizeof(x)`, so we will never be in trouble representation-wise.

**Problems:**

There are problems with this approach, particularly:

1. The [bit significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Order) and [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) affect the algorithm, and can render it useless. The principle can be adapted with the `#ifdef` statements, but I will leave this as an exercise for the reader ;)
2. While it addresses all 3 major number representations, it does not address the more exotic ones, like [offset binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary).
3. Left shift by a value equal to or greater than the width of the left operand is technically undefined behavior, but I don't know what you have to program on for it to not behave like this. And if you're ever in that situation, you will not have limitations like in this question.